# Best way to index large file

Tags: mongodb, go, boltdb

I have a file with about 100gb with a `word:tag` per line. I want to index these on `word` to easily get the list of `tag`s for a given word.

I wanted to save this on boltdb (mainly to checkout boltdb) but random write access is bad so I was aiming to index the file in some other way first, then moving all of it to boltdb without need to check for duplicates or de/serialisation of the `tag` list

So, for reference, if I simply read the file into memory (discarding data), I get about 8 MB/s.

If I write to boltdb files using code such as

```golang
        line := ""
        linesRead := 0
        for scanner.Scan() {
            line = scanner.Text()
            linesRead += 1
            data := strings.Split(line, ":")

            err = bucket.Put([]byte(data[0]), []byte(data[1]))
            logger.FatalErr(err)
            // commit on every N lines
            if linesRead % 10000 == 0 {
                err = tx.Commit()
                logger.FatalErr(err)
                tx, err = db.Begin(true)
                logger.FatalErr(err)
                bucket = tx.Bucket(name)
            }
        }
```

I get about 300 Kb/s speed and this is not even complete (as it's not adding `tag` to each `word`, only stores the last occurrence). So adding the array and JSON serialisation would definitely lower that speed...

So I gave mongodb a try

```golang
        index := mgo.Index{
            Key: []string{"word"},
            Unique: true,
            DropDups: false,
            Background: true,
            Sparse: true,
        }
        err = c.EnsureIndex(index)
        logger.FatalErr(err)

        line := ""
        linesRead := 0
        bulk := c.Bulk()

        for scanner.Scan() {
            line = scanner.Text()
            data := strings.Split(line, ":")
            bulk.Upsert(bson.M{"word": data[0]}, bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"tags": data[1]}})
            linesRead += 1

            if linesRead % 10000 == 0 {
                _, err = bulk.Run()
                logger.FatalErr(err)
                bulk = c.Bulk()
            }
        }
```

And I get about 300 Kb/s as well (though `Upsert` and `$push` here handle appending to the list).

I tried with a local MySQL instance as well (indexed on `word`) but speed was like 30x slower...

Comment: Try redis or redisearch.

Comment: Try in memory Sqlite

Comment: with sqlite there is a good post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite

Comment: I tried MySQL and it was worst than mongo, so SQLite wasn’t really an option.. in-memory either as it’s a 100gb file...

Comment: @FilipePina, by speed you mean the writing speed to the database ? If so, do you have the app, the database, and file on the same machine ? For MongoDB, you could try inserting all of them first without index, then add a foreground index once done.

Comment: yes, everything in same machine.. I could do that but I can't use the results while index isn't over so not sure if there's any gain from it... but I'll give it a go thanks. post suggested by @RichieK has very nice improvements on sqlite but it is still so slow...